# Match words in lists and replace that word in the second list with its pair in the first list

Tags: python, list, replace, match

I Have a list with word pairs. It looks like this:

```
words = ["I : You", "Me : You", "Mine : Yours"]
```

With input and split I create a new list from a sentence the user types.

What I want to do is to check if this new list (let's call it sentence) contains any words that the list "words" does. And if it does, I want it to replace that word with its pair from the "words"-list and then to print the sentence with the replaced word.

For example:
Program asks: "How are you?"
User answers: "I am well"
Program answers: "You are well"

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Looks like a dictionary, not  a list

Comment: If it is not a dict it should be

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
words = {"I" : "You", "Me" : "You", "Mine" : "Yours"}

sentence = "I am John Doe."

for word, replacement in words.items(): # works through the word pairs
    sentence.replace(word, replacement) # replacing with the counterpart
```

The sentence would now be `You are John Doe.`